# open random picture in new tab PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, image

I made a php line that pics a random picture from a certain directory:

```
<?php

  function random_pic($dir = 'pics')
  {
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
  }

?>
```

And now I dont know how get the random file to be open in a new tab..
The code that I am trying to work with is the one below:

```
<a href="" title="Click to open in new page!!">
  <img src=""<?php echo random_pic(); ?>" alt="" height="400" width="450" border="0"/>
</a>
```

I want to do so that when you click on the picture it opens in a new tab (or on the same page but without reloading),

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $random_pic = random_pic(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $random_pic; ?>" target="_blank" title="Click to open in new page!!"><img src="<?php echo $random_pic; ?>" alt="" height="400" width="450" border="0"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add target="_blank" to the anchor element to force the browser to open a new tab or window, depending on user's configuration.